# Process terminated with status -107374167

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error

I am trying to print the number of prime factors of a given number. My code works fine for some inputs, but for other inputs it's getting terminated and I can't understand why.

Sample Input:

```
1
561473
```

Output:

```
2
```

Sample Input:

```
1
10093
```

And the program terminates.

At some point, I thought it might be floating point exceptions, but I couldn't figure out the reason. I tried to debug every line of code, and found that the program terminates on this line of code:

```
while(ull(n%mem[j]) == 0) {
```

I am still unable to understand why this code breaks only for some particular inputs. I have tried without type casting also, still it gives me the same problem. I tried to print the exception, but the program just terminated, it didn't print any error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long ull;
ull RANGE = sqrt(10000), num;
unsigned int i;
set<ull> arr;
ull mem [10000000];

bool isPrime(unsigned long long n) {
    if(n%2 == 0)
        return false;
    for( int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i+=2) {
        if(n%i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void hungry() {
    while(true) {
        if(num > RANGE)
            break;
        if(isPrime(num))  {
            mem[i++] = num;
        }
        num += 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    num = 3; i = 1; mem [0] = 2;
    hungry();
    ull ip, n, temp;
    cin >> ip;
    while(ip) {
        cin >> n;
        arr.clear();
        temp = (ull) sqrt(n);
        if(temp > RANGE) {
            RANGE = temp;
            hungry();
        }
        if(n == 1)
            cout << 0 << "\n";
        else {
            while(n%2 == 0) {
                arr.insert(2);
                n = n/2;
            }
            for(int j = 1; mem[j] <= (ull)sqrt(n); j++){
                while(ull(n%mem[j]) == 0) {
                    arr.insert(mem[j]);
                    n = (ull)n/mem[j];
                }
            }

            if(n > 2)
                arr.insert(n);
            cout << arr.size() << "\n";
        }
        ip--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but `ull mem [10000000];` is allocating 76 **MB**.  That is *way* too much memory to allocate statically. If you need that much memory, allocate it dynamically instead, such as with a `std::vector`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What difference does it make? It takes up the same amount of memory at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `hungry` only fills in `mem` with primes up to the square root of `n`. When the `while (mem[j] <= (ull)sqrt(n))` loop reaches the end of these, `mem[j]` is `0`, not one of the prime numbers. Then you try to do `n % mem[j]`, which causes division by 0.

Change the loop to:

```
while (mem[j] > 0 && mem[j] <= (ull)sqrt(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a cout to see the value of mem[j] before the while statement. And for the problematic input, it gave 0 after a point. So there goes a floating point exception error. You can't take modulus with 0. The C++ Standard says:

> [...] If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is
>   undefined; [...]

```
cout << "Mem: " << mem[j] << endl;                                                                                           
while(ull(n%mem[j]) == 0) {                                                                                                  
    arr.insert(mem[j]);                                                                                                      
    n = (ull)n/mem[j];                                                                                                       
}
```

The output:

```
1 10093
Mem: 3
Mem: 5
Mem: 7
Mem: 11
Mem: 13
Mem: 17
Mem: 19
Mem: 23
Mem: 29
Mem: 31
Mem: 37
Mem: 41
Mem: 43
Mem: 47
Mem: 53
Mem: 59
Mem: 61
Mem: 67
Mem: 71
Mem: 73
Mem: 79
Mem: 83
Mem: 89
Mem: 97
Mem: 0
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```